# Azure pipeline using DotNetCoreCLI pack command on .NET Core 3.1 gives error

Tags: .net-core, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build and pack a class library into a NuGet using .NET Core 3.1. It all build fine on my dev machine, but the Azure pipeline build fails during the DotNetCoreCLI pack command. I was able to get the build working on after installing .NET Core 3.1 on the build machine using the UseDotNet. Build and tests run fine, so I believe the 3.1 version is installed correctly.

When I add the pack command, the step always fails. Here is the command I'm using:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Package NuGet
  inputs: 
    command: 'pack'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
    outputDir: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/packages'
```

I get the following error during this step:

> /opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/3.1.101/Sdks/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack/build/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(198,5):
>   error NU5026: The file
>   '/home/vsts/work/1/s/ClassLib31/bin/**Debug**/netcoreapp3.1/ClassLib31.dll'
>   to be packed was not found on disk.
>   [/home/vsts/work/1/s/ClassLib31/ClassLib31.csproj]

Notice the path above is looking bin Debug folder, but this is a Release build. All of the tasks are using the same BuildConfiguration variable, but in this task it appears to be looking for the dll in the Debug folder. Any ideas why?

Additional notes:
- This build script works fine for .NET Core 3.0 projects. I tried switching the library to target 3.0 and removed the 3.1 installation step. Pack works as expected.
- This build script works when I build the Debug version of the library (as you'd expect, since the task is looking in that bin folder).

Comment: Very strange. According to your description, the issue seems to come from `.net core3.1`, but I test it with `.net core 3.1` on the hosted agent `ubuntu-16.04` and `ubuntu-18.04`, it works fine. Not sure where the argument `debug` comes from, how about specify the directly argument like: arguments: `--configuration Release`?

Comment: I tried with specifying --configuration Release in the arguments, but that didn't help. It still gave the same error with the debug path. I am also on a ubuntu-18.04 hosted agent. And I am using the DotNetCoreCLI pack command, not the NuGetCommand command.

Comment: Found a workaround in the meantime. Replacing the DotNetCoreCLI pack command with the NuGetCommand pack fixes the issue. With that command, I can package the .NET Core 3.1 library into a nuget... Weird that it works with that build task but not the DotNetCoreCLI task.

Comment: Yes, I also test it with DotNetCoreCLI pack command, I haven't heard other voices about this issue either. So, this issue should be more related to the environment, like project file. Anyway, I am glad that you have resolved your question with workaround, would you please convert your comment to the answer before you solution for the issue. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.  Thanks.

Comment: This is a workaround, but not the final answer. The DotNetCoreCLI pack command should work for .NET Core 3.1 projects... shouldn't have to use the NuGetCommand.

Comment: Yes, I know it is a workaround not the solution, but since we could not reproduce this issue, and no any other communities report this issue. So, we could not provide a solution. Would you mind share us a sample by onedrive to reproduce this (Do not include personal privacy information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more time debugging the build pipeline, I discovered that I had mismatched case the BuildConfiguration variable in a couple of places, which caused this to fail in the pack command. I discovered this while combing through the logs for each step.

It seems that if the case mismatch is in earlier commands (like build and test) they default to the release build. But for the pack command it seems to default to look in the debug bin folder. Once I discovered this and cleaned up the script, it works fine now .NET Core 3.1 builds.

Comment: It's unclear exactly how you changed the script so I'm assuming that you have left the `arguments` argument untouched. If so, I'm surprised you were able to get it running. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#arguments) states that "This input only currently accepts arguments for `build`, `publish`, `run`, `test`, `custom`. If you would like to add arguments for a command not listed, use `custom`."

Comment: @Moss I had similar issue and posted the solution in this thread, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

[DotNetCoreCLI@2 Pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#arguments) command does not support `arguments` argument.

> Arguments to the selected command. For example, build configuration,
> output folder, runtime. The arguments depend on the command selected
> **Note: This input only currently accepts arguments for `build`, `publish`,
> `run`, `test`, `custom`.** If you would like to add arguments for a command
> not listed, use `custom`.

You may use `arguments` argument for `build` command and `configuration` argument for `pack` command:

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Build
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      arguments: '--configuration Release'
      ...

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Pack
    inputs:
      command: 'pack'
      configuration: 'Release'
      ...
```

There is another workaround, but note that in this case `packagesToPack` argument does not work:

```
# command: 'pack'
command: custom
custom: pack
arguments: '--configuration Release'
```